# PowerShell: Headers, Footers and/or Frames in CLI

Tags: powershell, header, footer, frames

While running a series of scripts through a command line interface, is there a way to add a header and footer while the body is scrolling verbose feedback of the currently running script?

The header would have information regarding the currently running script. The footer would have info to the user on controlling certain scripts and how to pause or stop the script.

Any ideas if anything likes this exists?

Comment: If header should contain progress info, take a look on Write-Progress cmdlet ([Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ProgressBarsInPowerShell.aspx) has nice example of how to use it)

Comment: This looks very interesting and might be a solution. I'll play with that. Still hoping for something closer to actual headers and footers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the window title, which could function kind of like a header - though I don't know if it will give you exactly what you are looking for:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Your Custom Header"
```

The suggestion by [jumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417860/powershell-headers-footers-and-or-frames-in-cli#comment13442063_10417860) to use the Write-Progress cmdlet is probably about as good as you are going to get as far as a footer goes in pure PowerShell.

Another option would be to host the PowerShell runtime in a WinForms/WPF app that would give you proper headers/footers - though that may be completely overkill and not fit your needs at all either. In an overly simple and contrived example you would do something like this is in C#:

```
// include the System.Management.Automation assembly & namespace
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-Process");
foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke()) {
  Console.WriteLine(result.Members["ProcessName"].Value);
}
```

Instead of writing to the console, you would perhaps dump the output to a TextBox or something more appropriate.

The last option would be to use the ability for the console to set the [CursorPosition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostrawuserinterface.cursorposition.aspx) property. This is once again kind of a hack as you would be overwriting output that would be scrolling by, but if your script has limited output - this may work:

```
$pos = $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
$newPos = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates 0,20
$Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $newPos
"Here is my footer on starting at the first character of line 20"
$Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $pos
```

You could dynamically inspect the `$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height` property to set your footer near the bottom of the window. Just remember, that by default the text will scroll if there is a lot of output - which will include old versions of your footer scrolling up the screen as well.

Comment: I guess this is as close to a pure PowerShell solution I can get. Thanks for the advice.